# Magnitude of Sample Weights in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Keras model.fit supports per-sample weights. What is the range of acceptable values for these weights? Must they sum to 1 across all training samples? Or does keras accept any weight values and then perform some sort of normalization? The keras source includes, e.g. `training_utils.standardize_weights` but that does not appear to be doing statistical standardization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_utils.py), I've found that you should be able to pass any acceptable numerical values (within overflow bounds) for both sample weights and class weights.  They do not need to sum to 1 across all training samples and each weight may be greater than one.  The only sort of normalization that appears to be happening is taking the max of 2D class weight inputs.

If both class weights and samples weights are provided, it provides the product of the two.

I think the unspoken component here is that the activation function should be dealing with normalization.